# Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single column with string value as:

```
[04/11/2023,"New addition","","new additional of fund","This, Adam, Kyle","5.00","11147474"]
```

In this value, there are 7 commas, which is like 7 columns that need to be extracted. Some values can have a comma withing the actual value, but those are wrapped with double quotes.

How to do I extract these values into separate column?

```
[04/11/2023], [New addition], [NULL], [new additional of fund], [This, Adam, Kyle], [5.00],[11147474]
```

This seems simple enough but can't figure out how to do in SQL.

Comment: "This seems simple enough". It's really not, though. "Simple" CSV data has a surprising number of edge cases that can break things, of which commas as part of the data are just one, and databases provide only limited tools to help. Instead, they expect you to handle this kind of thing _before_ you add it to the DB, and so this is what we call a **broken** schema. The data should be split by the client **at insert/update time**, or returned to the client in full to split there.

Comment: It's like an *almost* valid JSON, except for the date. Maybe you can get the format changed?

Comment: Why didn't the first column get any quotes? It could've saved you some pain. if that's the only unquoted one, you could probably cheat and find the first comma, then stuff quotes around it, and finally convert to json array and pray someone didn't throw some dust in the other values

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data sample resembles JSON.

That's why we can convert it into a legit JSON, and easily tokenize it after that into separate columns.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('[04/11/2023,"New addition","","new additional of fund","This, Adam, Kyle","5.00","11147474"]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID --, j
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[0]') AS col0
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[1]') AS col1
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[2]') AS col2
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[3]') AS col3
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[4]') AS col4
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[5]') AS col5
    , JSON_VALUE(j, '$[6]') AS col6
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF(STUFF(tokens,12,0, '"'),2,0,'"')) AS t1(j);
```

**Output**

| ID | col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04/11/2023 | New addition |  | new additional of fund | This, Adam, Kyle | 5.00 | 11147474 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(200) = '[04/11/2023,"New addition","","new additional 
of fund","This, Adam, Kyle","5.00","11147474"]'
SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, 2, LEN(@Str)-1)
SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, LEN(@Str)-2)
SET @Str = REPLACE(@Str, '","', ';')
SET @Str = REPLACE(@Str, ',"', ';')
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Str,';')
```